# Handling errors in promise chaining in react-redux application

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, error-handling, redux

This is in continuation to [Handling async errors in react redux application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46376290/handling-async-errors-in-react-redux-application)

In my react-redux application

How can I handle a case where I make an API call and on its success I want to make another API call and on its success another API call? I would like to handle errors on each calls. Propose a solution without any side effects and anti-pattern.

My Code

```
   // sends a request to server 
const makeAsyncCall2 = (arg, response) => {
    const serverArguments = {};

    const req = request
            .post(`${baseUrl}/someotheraction.action`)
            .send(serverArguments)
            .type('form')
            .setAuthHeaders();

    return req.endAsync();
};     

// sends a request to server
const makeAsyncCall1= () => {
    const serverArguments = {};

    const req = request
            .post(`${baseUrl}/somexyz.action`)
            .send(serverArguments)
            .type('form')
            .setAuthHeaders();

    return req.endAsync();
};



   async function makeServerCalls(args, length) {
    // convert args to two dimensional array, chunks of given length [[1,2,3], [4,5,6,], [7,8]]
    const batchedArgs = args.reduce((rows, key, index) => (index % length === 0 ? rows.push([key])
        : rows[rows.length - 1].push(key)) && rows, []);

    const responses = [];

    for (const batchArgs of batchedArgs) {
        responses.push(
            // wait for a chunk to complete, before firing the next chunk of calls
            await Promise.all(
                batchArgs.map((arg) =>
                    request
                        .get(`${baseUrl}/something.cgi`)
                        .query(arg)
                        .endAsync()
                        .then((response) => {
                            makeAsyncCall2(arg, response)
                                .then((res) => console.log(res))
                                .catch((err) => console.log(err))
                            return response;
                        })
                        .catch((error) => {
                            makeAsyncCall2(arg, error)
                                .then((res) => console.log(res))
                                .catch((err) => console.log(err))
                            return error;
                        })
                )
            )
        );
    }

    // wait for all calls to finish
    return Promise.all(responses);
}


// Call starts here 
makeAsyncCall1()
              .then(() => makeServerCalls(args, 3))
              .then((responses) => onAllPromiseResolve(responses));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a single function to handle a possible error or multiple functions to handle each possible error individually, chain `.catch()` with error handler function as parameter to each `Promise` or function which returns a `Promise`.

Comment: Why do you `return response` and `return error` outside of `Promise` chain?

Comment: Note, `makeAsyncCall2` is not `return`ed from `.then()`

Comment: I don't want to return what is returned by makeAsyncCall2, but I would like to log if something wrong happens with makeAsyncCall2 and prevent  "bluebird.js:1542 Unhandled rejection Errors" coming from unsuccessful makeAsynCall2 and makeAsyncCall1.

Comment: Chain `.catch()` to `makeAsyncCall1()` and `Promise.all(responses)` to handle the rejection

Comment: I didnt get how?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155141/discussion-between-lokesh-agrawal-and-guest271314).